# Simple server in python 2 how to get recv to return 0

Tags: python, sockets

Here is full code of my simple socket python server. It returns errno 10035 upon connection from the client? Also I included 'c.setblocking(0)' because recv was blocking c socket

```
import socket

def Main():

    host = ""
    port = 80
    indic = 1
    data = ""
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.bind((host, port))

    s.listen(1)
    c, addr = s.accept()
    c.setblocking(0)
    print "Connection from: " + str(addr)
    while indic:
        data = c.recv(4096)
        if not data: indic = 0
        print "From connected user: " + str(data)
    c.send("<html><head></head></html>")
    c.close()
    exit()


Main()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are trying to bind port 80. This is a reserved port, and you can't simply bind it with your application. (There is a way of doing that, I'm just not sure howto). When I try to run your code I get a different error:

```
error: [Errno 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden 
by its access permissions
```

When I changed it to a different port (e.g, 8080) and put `host = "localhost"` I ran your code successfully.

```
===================== RESTART: C:\Python27\tests\test.py =====================
Connection from: ('127.0.0.1', 54287)
```

There is a great [Socket Programming HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/sockets.html) available on python.org.

Comment: I'm running it on windows. I changed host and port also but it still gives the error 'a non-blocking socket operation could not be completed immediately'

Comment: Please share your client code. I just opened a new browser to http://127.0.0.1:8080. Or do you get this error when executing the server code?

Comment: Yes even in browser. It points an error to `data = c.recv(4096)` errno 10035. I get this error in cmd of server code.

Comment: It receives and prints out the data but then it appears to be doing nothing when I delete the `c.setblocking(0)`. I want it to exit the loop and send the html